# How to load a local image into a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I'm writing in a js file and here is how my buttons look like

```
var myButton = $('<button type="button" style="display:inline">Translate Right</button>');
    myButton.css({"margin-top":"5px", "float":"left"});
```

Now I would like to replace the "Translate right" text with an icon. I tried :

```
   var myButton = $('<button type="button" style="display:inline">Translate Right</button>');
       myButton.css({"margin-top":"5px", "float":"left"});
       $('body').append(myButton); 
      myButton.html('<img src="path\to\image">'); // backslash because I'm using windows
```

But it is not working. I have an empty button. And I have this error: Not allowed to load local resource.
I changed url with src (I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do like this), I don't have the error anymorre but the button is still empty

ps : In my code, I append myButton to the body in another way because, the file I'm writing in, is not my index file but the problem is not here (I have already tried with a different src http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png) and it worked .
Could you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Use `src` :  `myButton.attr("src","path/to/icon");`

Comment: Why are you using javascript to apply your css?

Comment: Can you post your full process (creating, adding the button, adding the class) that you have now? We're missing some steps that could cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
var myButton = $('<button type="button" style="display:inline">Translate Right</button>');
myButton.css({"margin-top":"5px", "float":"left"});
```

And then:

```
myButton.html('<img src="path/to/icon" />');
```

But you should use `<button>` with this method...

[**<kbd>JSBin Demo</kbd>**](http://jsbin.com/isazac/2/edit)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually it works with an "external image" . But in my case, the icon is a local file. Here is the error I got : Not allowed to load local resource. How should I do?

Comment: @user1499220 So, the issue you're facing (is not how to put an image on your button, it) is how to load a local image onto a button when an external one works? [Does this help?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Not+allowed+to+load+local+resource)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a psuedo element, documented here: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

Also, I'd recommend not putting your css in your javascript but instead just change the class name via javascript, as described here: http://smacss.com/book/state

ie:

```
.myButton:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: (myIcon.png);
}
```

Edit:

I think something has gone wrong with your code between trying various things. This JSFiddle works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4C6e3/

Comment: I separated the css from the js file. Then,  var myButton=$('<button type=submit" value="">');
    myButton.addClass('myButton') ;
    Then I appended it to the body. But I still have the same result(empty button)